# I converted my database to utf-8 but my old data is still in windows-1251. How to convert it?

Tags: mysql, database, encoding, utf-8, type-conversion

I want to convert my database to utf-8. What I have done up to now is set the server to read utf-8 and the database is converted by using this query:

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Now all new information is seen and the things that were broken are now fine. The problem is that the old data is seen as �. This, in my opinion, is due to the fact that the old data is written in windows-1251 (I think at least and I am not 100% sure).

I found out that I need to dump the data:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p database -r utf8.dump
```

and then import it:

```
mysql -uroot -p --default-character-set=utf8 database 
mysql> SET names 'utf8' 
mysql> SOURCE utf8.dump
```

This is what I saw from here: https://makandracards.com/makandra/595-dumping-and-importing-from-to-mysql-in-an-utf-8-safe-way

The problem is that I have absolutely no idea where and how to do this. 
All I have access is to the web hosting control panel and I have **not** set up anything on my computer. Therefore, I have no idea how to connect the database to the command shell and so on. What next steps should I do to convert the data to utf-8? Please, any detailed explanation would be great due to the fact that this is the first time for me doing something like this.

// I have a Mac and a Windows machine, but not a Linux at the moment.

Thank you!

Comment: Recommended reading: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html and  http://kunststube.net/encoding/

Comment: Running the ALTER DATABASE statement changes the *default* character set for the database. The default character set applies to *new* tables that are created without a character set specified.  The default character set for a table applies to new columns created in the table, which do not have a character set specified.  The ALTER DATABASE statement does not change the character set of existing tables and columns.

Answer (score 0):

The charset and collation of the *database* are the *default* for any subsequently created tables.  The *table* setting are the defaults for columns.

For each table, so this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO utf8mb4;
```